# switch case inside other switch case

Tags: android

i have a expandable listview. when selecting an item from this list, childd and parentt variables change. it works fine. but after that, the code below is written, but only last cases work :

```
  switch (groupp)
                 {
                 case 1:
                   {
                     switch (childd)
                     {
                     case 1:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("1") ;}
                     case 2:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("2") ;}
                     case 3:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("3") ;}
                     case 4:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("4") ;  }
                     case 5:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("5") ;}  
                       }                         
                     }

                 case 2:
                 {
                     switch (childd)
                     {
                     case 1:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("a") ;}
                     case 2:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("b") ;}
                     case 3:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("c") ;}
                     case 4:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("d") ; } 
                     case 5:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("e") ; }    
                     case 6:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("f") ; }                             
                     }
                 }

             }
```

after running this code, SelectedGenre sets to : 5 and selected mozoo sets to : f. but groupp is not 1 and childd5

Comment: where are the break statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use break statement after each case complete.
because switch case says that if any of case is matched rest all will be executed if there is no termination. so use break statement after each case;

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `break` in your switch case.

Try this:

```
 switch (groupp)
                 {
                 case 1:
                   {
                     switch (childd)
                     {
                     case 1:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("1") ;break;}
                     case 2:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("2") ;break;}
                     case 3:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("3") ;break;}
                     case 4:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("4") ;  break;}
                     case 5:
                         {SelectedGenre.setText("5") ;break;}  
                       }                         
                     }
                 break;
                 case 2:
                 {
                     switch (childd)
                     {
                     case 1:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("a") ;break;}
                     case 2:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("b") ;break;}
                     case 3:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("c") ;break;}
                     case 4:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("d") ; break;} 
                     case 5:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("e") ; break;}    
                     case 6:
                         {SelectedMozoo.setText("f") ; break;}                             
                     }break;
                 }

             }
```